# How do I convert this Pandas DataFrame into a specific JSON format?

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I'm trying to figure out how I can go from this Pandas DataFrame:

[image: Pandas DataFrame]

to this JSON:

[image: JSON]

I've tried the dataframe.to_json method (and its various return orientations) but that's not giving me the exact desired output. I've had a good read around online, but everything is very fiddly. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

The raw dataFrame is here incase:

```
NETWORK_USERID  TALK_STATUS TALK_STATUS_EXPIRY  CATEGORY    CATEGORY_EXPIRY
0   f40daf16-f069-4c1d-ac2a-d1504f0fc147    Talker  15/12/2020  MN_FFBQ 23/12/2019
1   4d3e9e50-f88b-4c0b-a700-881474f992ab    Lurker  15/12/2020  MN_FFBQ 23/12/2019
2   c2e2fa63-efad-4b7d-b11e-77d9c8692677    Lurker  15/12/2020  MN_FFBQ 23/12/2019
3   c46a2af4-0c20-486e-9ae0-6323269f252d    Lurker  15/12/2020  MN_FFBQ 23/12/2019
4   f6f88be2-dca6-4129-93ed-2b32a633e1ec    Talker  15/12/2020  MN_FFBQ 23/12/2019
```

Comment: Hi HatB, welcome to StackOverflow. Please read through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and add what code you have tried so far.

Comment: e.g. using [pandas.DataFrame.to_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)?

Comment: The desired output looks like a mix of csv and json. Why not just output to csv using df.to_csv()? When used without a filename, this prints a csv-formatted string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you :

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """
NETWORK_USERID,TALK_STATUS,TALK_STATUS_EXPIRY,CATEGORY,CATEGORY_EXPIRY
f40daf16-f069-4c1d-ac2a-d1504f0fc147,Talker,15/12/2020,MN_FFBQ,23/12/2019
4d3e9e50-f88b-4c0b-a700-881474f992ab,Lurker,15/12/2020,MN_FFBQ,23/12/2019
c2e2fa63-efad-4b7d-b11e-77d9c8692677,Lurker,15/12/2020,MN_FFBQ,23/12/2019
c46a2af4-0c20-486e-9ae0-6323269f252d,Lurker,15/12/2020,MN_FFBQ,23/12/2019
f6f88be2-dca6-4129-93ed-2b32a633e1ec,Talker,15/12/2020,MN_FFBQ,23/12/2019
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),sep=',')

v = df.values.tolist()
lst = []
col1=['value','expiry']

for row in v:
    lst.append([row[0],'['+str(dict(zip(col1, [row[3],row[4]])))+']'])

df1 = pd.DataFrame(lst,columns=['NETWORK_USERID','CATEGORY'])
print(df1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an apposite function provided by pandas library: `to_json` function.

Documentation ⬇️

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

Comment: Thank you Liuk, but I tried the to_json call and it still didn't give me the desired output. I've edited my original answer now :)